# How does $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' work?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have in my gitlab.yml file,

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

Before adding that my pipeline was working fine. I just wanted to make it such that the job above was *only* run on `merge_request_event`. Now that I added that, the *behavior* seems to change. How is this rule implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because despite looking like a conditional with an `if:` statement,

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

This **actually does change the behavior**, [it enables "Merge Request Pipelines" by satisfying the criteria,](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html).

> Your project’s .gitlab-ci.yml file must be configured with jobs that run in merge request pipelines. To do this, you can use:
>
> - rules.
> - only/except.

Assume we have a repo `foo` and we fork it into `bar`. If we open a merge request (adding a new file) from `bar` to `foo`, you'll see the same high level overview,

[image: New merge request]

But adding the rule `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'` causes a few different things to happen,

- The pipeline is no longer a "Push Pipeline" it's a p"Merge Request Pipeline"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) and it has a different tag.
- The pipeline is no longer run on the fork, but from the "base" project
- The commit the pipeline runs on is no longer run on the fork, but from `refs/merge_requests` in the "base" project.

I believe this gives a better idea of how this process works, but you should read the full official documentation page on ["Merge Request Pipelines"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) to compliment any understanding this gives.

## Without *"Merge Request Pipelines"*

However, everything is different from this point on. When you're **NOT** using "Merged Request Pipelines", the merge request page will link to the pipeline like this,

[image: link to pipeline]

Note *"Pipeline"* here is more correctly "Push Pipeline". If you click on that number, the pipeline itself will show under `bar` **the fork** for example under this path `bar/-/pipelines/455884`

[image: Pipelines in bar]

And it will show the job,

[image: Job detail from bar]

If you dump the environment from that job you'll see

```
CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE=push
```

And this is true. The pipeline **is running on the branch** (in this case `foobar`), and that can be seen on `bar/-/tree/foobar`,

[image: foobar branch]

## With *"Merge Request Pipelines"*

Now let's add the configuration and rerun,

```yaml
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
```

Now you'll see this on the merge request sitting on `foo`,

[image: Foo's merge request]

Immediately take note to it saying *"Merge request pipeline"* rather than *"Pipeline"*. When you click on that pipeline number #455999 you'll be taken **NOT** to bar's pipelines, as you were above, but instead to foo's pipelines, `foo/-/pipelines/455999` and here you'll see this summary which has the tag `merge_request`.

[image: Merge Request Pipeline summary]

Clicking on the job's tab, you'll be taken to foo's jobs, `foo/-/pipelines/455999/builds` and you'll see this,

[image: Merged Request Pipeline Job]

And that's showing you that the merge request no longer comes from the branch `foobar` in reality, it's pulled foobar down to the git merge request directory `foo/-/commits/refs/merge-requests/1/head` and the merge request now points to that, which resembles the commit **AFTER** it has merged.

---

[I posted this comment on the GitLab Rule Epic to let them know my thoughts on this](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/2783#note_1826457181)