# Is it possible to update a Merge Request that runs in the parent project with GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repository called `foo` and I've forked it into `bar`. I want to write a pipeline that modifies Merge Requests adding a [chore commit](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/19087/18965) such that when `bar` sends a Merge Request to `foo` it will run the CI which will block the merge until the pipeline completes, and if the pipeline completes successfully it will kick off a job which will modify the merge request. From this point the merge requests either goes in complete and with the chore commit, or it fails.

On the basis of `ci_allow_fork_pipelines_to_run_in_parent_project`,

- If set to false, the Merge Request pipeline will run on the head repo (`bar`)
- If set to true (default), run Merge Request pipeline will on the base rep (`foo`)

Obviously if set to false, this is the same basic [process as outlined here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/19070/18965) (and that becomes massively easier when [`CI_JOB_TOKEN` allows you to push to the repo](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/19070/18965).

However, if set to true and you want the Merge Request to run on `foo`, what route is possible? You can't currently write to `refs/merge-requests/*` even with the `-f` flag,

```sh
❯ git push origin -f HEAD:refs/merge-requests/1/head
Enumerating objects: 7, done.
Counting objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 489 bytes | 489.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://gitlab.acme.net/evancarroll/foo.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/merge-requests/1/head (deny updating a hidden ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.acme.net/evancarroll/foo.git'
```

Note that

> deny updating a hidden ref

[Seems to be intentional](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17636), however if I could do this, this would make current configuration easier because forks wouldn't have to manually generate a write token and then store it as a CI variable.